# Ubuntu live session shut down while trying to install 16.04.1 ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

Hi I am trying to install Ubuntu and it keeps shutting my laptop down with the following message "Hi live session user you have open files you might want to save. Would you like to:" and 3 icons appear under it, a restart, shutdown and sleep but it shuts my laptop down automatically.
I am trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows with a UEFI USB stick.
Thanks in advanced

Comment: At which point exactly that messages comes up?

Comment: Never had this kind of problem myself but consider these possible solutions :
Try to install your ubuntu image on another USB stick, maybe it's corrupted; Try another image of ubuntu/kubuntu/xubuntu, just to know if yourimage isn't itself corrupted (It happens); You don't have to launch ubuntu in live mode to install it, you can immediately choose the install option, maybe the live session is causing a problem. If none of this works maybe your hardware is not supported by Ubuntu. Try adding screenshots or be more descriptive about your problem.